# Add endpoint dynamically to camel Context using Java DSL

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

I do like to create/add client endpoint ( Endpoint.class ) to camel context using java DSL ( not to define it in blueprint.xml).

In this time I have this endpoint specified in blueprint.xml:

```
<!-- SOAP client settings -->
<camelcxf:cxfEndpoint id="primeSmsMT2"
                      address="{{prime2.url}}"
                      wsdlURL="META-INF/wsdl/primeSmsMT.wsdl">
    <camelcxf:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPInInterceptor" />
    </camelcxf:inInterceptors>
</camelcxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

BUT I like to create it dynamically. I search in this way and I didn't find something.

An example is this but is not working:

```
CxfEndpoint primeSmsMTEndpoint = getContext().getEndpoint("cxf: 
{prime2.url}", CxfEndpoint.class);
primeSmsMTEndpoint.setWsdlURL("META-INF/wsdl/primeSmsMT.wsdl");
```

Could you please help me?
Thank you.